# Trying to figure out how to make my code trigger with html buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out how to make my code trigger with html buttons like:

```
<button data-animation="1" class="rounded" onClick="gotoPage2(0)"> PAGE 2 </button>
```

The idea is that when the button is clicked it uses the information from "data-animation" to trigger the associated css3 animation. I have 67 cases of animations in the script which adds and removes css3 animations whenever someone toggles via clicking the menu list items (dl-menu).

I am trying to find out the best way how I could fit in another section of code in the script which allows me to do the same thing as with my menu list items but with "html buttons"

Any feedback is appeciated.

This is the script:

```
var PageTransitions = (function() {

    var $main = $( '#pt-main' ),
        $pages = $main.children( 'div.pt-page' ),
        $iterate = $( '#iterateEffects' ),
        animcursor = 1,
        pagesCount = $pages.length,
        current = 0,
        isAnimating = false,
        endCurrPage = false,
        endNextPage = false,
        animEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
            'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
            'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
            'animation' : 'animationend'
        },
        // animation end event name
        animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
        // support css animations
        support = Modernizr.cssanimations;

    function init() {

        $pages.each( function() {
            var $page = $( this );
            $page.data( 'originalClassList', $page.attr( 'class' ) );
        } );

        $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' );

        $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu( {
            animationClasses : { in : 'dl-animate-in-2', out : 'dl-animate-out-2' },
            onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                nextPage( el.data( 'animation' ) );
            }
        } );

        $iterate.on( 'click', function() {
            if( isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            if( animcursor > 67 ) {
                animcursor = 1;
            }
            nextPage( animcursor );
            ++animcursor;
        } );

    }

    function nextPage( animation ) {

        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }

        isAnimating = true;

        var $currPage = $pages.eq( current );

        if( current < pagesCount - 1 ) {
            ++current;
        }
        else {
            current = 0;
        }

        var $nextPage = $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' ),
            outClass = '', inClass = '';

        switch( animation ) {

            case 1:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToLeft';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight';
                break;
            case 2:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToRight';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft';
                break;
            case 3:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToTop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom';
                break;
            case 4:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToBottom';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTop';
                break;
            case 5:
                outClass = 'pt-page-fade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 6:
                outClass = 'pt-page-fade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 7:
                outClass = 'pt-page-fade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 8:
                outClass = 'pt-page-fade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTop pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 9:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToLeftFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRightFade';
                break;
            case 10:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToRightFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeftFade';
                break;
            case 11:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToTopFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottomFade';
                break;
            case 12:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToBottomFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTopFade';
                break;
            case 13:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToLeftEasing pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight';
                break;
            case 14:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToRightEasing pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft';
                break;
            case 15:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToTopEasing pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom';
                break;
            case 16:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToBottomEasing pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTop';
                break;
            case 17:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDown';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 18:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDown';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 19:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDown';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 20:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDown';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTop pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 21:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDown';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUpDown pt-page-delay300';
                break;
            case 22:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDownUp';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUp pt-page-delay300';
                break;
            case 23:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToLeft pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUp';
                break;
            case 24:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToRight pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUp';
                break;
            case 25:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToTop pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUp';
                break;
            case 26:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToBottom pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUp';
                break;
            case 27:
                outClass = 'pt-page-scaleDownCenter';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUpCenter pt-page-delay400';
                break;
            case 28:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRightSideFirst';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight pt-page-delay200 pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 29:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateLeftSideFirst';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft pt-page-delay200 pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 30:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateTopSideFirst';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTop pt-page-delay200 pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 31:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateBottomSideFirst';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom pt-page-delay200 pt-page-ontop';
                break;
            case 32:
                outClass = 'pt-page-flipOutRight';
                inClass = 'pt-page-flipInLeft pt-page-delay500';
                break;
            case 33:
                outClass = 'pt-page-flipOutLeft';
                inClass = 'pt-page-flipInRight pt-page-delay500';
                break;
            case 34:
                outClass = 'pt-page-flipOutTop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-flipInBottom pt-page-delay500';
                break;
            case 35:
                outClass = 'pt-page-flipOutBottom';
                inClass = 'pt-page-flipInTop pt-page-delay500';
                break;
            case 36:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateFall pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-scaleUp';
                break;
            case 37:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateOutNewspaper';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateInNewspaper pt-page-delay500';
                break;
            case 38:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushLeft';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight';
                break;
            case 39:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushRight';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft';
                break;
            case 40:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushTop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom';
                break;
            case 41:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushBottom';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTop';
                break;
            case 42:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushLeft';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotatePullRight pt-page-delay180';
                break;
            case 43:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushRight';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotatePullLeft pt-page-delay180';
                break;
            case 44:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushTop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotatePullBottom pt-page-delay180';
                break;
            case 45:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushBottom';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotatePullTop pt-page-delay180';
                break;
            case 46:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateFoldLeft';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRightFade';
                break;
            case 47:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateFoldRight';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeftFade';
                break;
            case 48:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateFoldTop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottomFade';
                break;
            case 49:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateFoldBottom';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromTopFade';
                break;
            case 50:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToRightFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateUnfoldLeft';
                break;
            case 51:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToLeftFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateUnfoldRight';
                break;
            case 52:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToBottomFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateUnfoldTop';
                break;
            case 53:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToTopFade';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateUnfoldBottom';
                break;
            case 54:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomLeftOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomLeftIn';
                break;
            case 55:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomRightOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomRightIn';
                break;
            case 56:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomTopOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomTopIn';
                break;
            case 57:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomBottomOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomBottomIn';
                break;
            case 58:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeLeftOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeLeftIn';
                break;
            case 59:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeRightOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeRightIn';
                break;
            case 60:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeTopOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeTopIn';
                break;
            case 61:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeBottomOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCubeBottomIn';
                break;
            case 62:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselLeftOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselLeftIn';
                break;
            case 63:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselRightOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselRightIn';
                break;
            case 64:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselTopOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselTopIn';
                break;
            case 65:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselBottomOut pt-page-ontop';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateCarouselBottomIn';
                break;
            case 66:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateSidesOut';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateSidesIn pt-page-delay200';
                break;
            case 67:
                outClass = 'pt-page-rotateSlideOut';
                inClass = 'pt-page-rotateSlideIn';
                break;

        }

        $currPage.addClass( outClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
            $currPage.off( animEndEventName );
            endCurrPage = true;
            if( endNextPage ) {
                onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
            }
        } );

        $nextPage.addClass( inClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
            $nextPage.off( animEndEventName );
            endNextPage = true;
            if( endCurrPage ) {
                onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
            }
        } );

        if( !support ) {
            onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
        }

    }

    function onEndAnimation( $outpage, $inpage ) {
        endCurrPage = false;
        endNextPage = false;
        resetPage( $outpage, $inpage );
        isAnimating = false;
    }

    function resetPage( $outpage, $inpage ) {
        $outpage.attr( 'class', $outpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) );
        $inpage.attr( 'class', $inpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) + ' pt-page-current' );
    }

    init();

    return { init : init };

})();
```

Comment: why not just do `function PageTransitions(){...}` instead of the weird variable assignment thing you're doing. And also, your button triggers a function that doesn't exist (I don't see `gotoPage()` function anywhere in your code. If you fix all that and it doesn't work, try using `element.addEventListener` instead of an inline handler

Comment: @Markasoftware Hi, here the jsfiddle where im trying to do the same with buttons. I tried to integrate my jsfiddle code into this code here and make my buttons take the animation from "data-animation" just like the menu list but somehow i fail. Not sure where to start

Comment: you are right, I forgot about the click function, sorry. Took that from my jsfiddle. Im so confused, im messing this up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use cases in your `nextPage()` function, I suggest you the remove the on click function in HTML and write like this:

`<button type="button" data-animation="1" class="btn">PAGE 1</button>`

you can write many buttons as long as you use the `class="btn"`

then, you can bind on click event to buttons which have btn class, to trigger your animations in `nextPage()` function

```
$(".btn").on('click', function (event) {
    var dataAnimation = $(this).attr('data-animation');
    nextPage(dataAnimation);
});
```

now the value in `data-animation` will be your case number in `nextPage()` function.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rGkd/1/) that maybe you can continue work on and add your `nextPage()` function

Comment: So I get the same effect as in Jsfiddle I created right? jsfiddle.net/tb2H3 . I really like the way you explained this. I will study this further and test it out now

Comment: @user3025918 If you rewrite the `nextPage()` function properly, I believe you would get the same effect as your jsfiddle

Comment: it works but somehow it doesnt trigger the animation. I added the code to my javascript. Page swap works, just the transition fails somehow. You are right, I will have to rewrite the function. Is my jsfiddle ok though?

Comment: oh hang on, isnt my nextPage function fine within this context? Its supposed to work actually

Comment: I didn't really look into the entire js codes in your jsfiddle. Ideally this will work if you write your `nextPage()` function as a global function so that it can be accessed by the onclick event function.

Answer (score 0):

you actualy need the function gotoPage2(n);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tb2H3/   I got a jsfiddle of what im working on. Im trying to integrate that button functionality in my original code which you see here but not sure where to start and how I make my buttons take the animation from "data-animation" and the cases